# How to solve "TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined" in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I was just doing a simple destructure in react but it shows the title as an error message and I don't know why.
Here is my code:

```
const {correct_answer, incorrect_answers} = data[0]
const arr = [correct_answer, ...incorrect_answers]
console.log(arr)
```

After running this code this shows the following error message in browser console:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'correct_answer' of 'data[0]' as it is undefined.
```

Can anyone see where I am wrong?

Comment: Is it `correct_answer` an array as well? Try: `const arr = [...correct_answer, ...incorrect_answers]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle the null case for data[0].

```js
const {correct_answer, incorrect_answers} = data[0] || {};
```

Or if you are using a newer ECMA version:

```js
const {correct_answer, incorrect_answers} = data[0] ?? {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems likely that `data` does not contain an element in its 0th position? Have you tried doing `console.log(data)` to see what's actually inside it?

Answer (score 1):

The **data[0]** is probably undefined so is the error.

You can assign default values for the destructured variables. Assuming they are arrays you can do like below.

```
const {correct_answer= [], incorrect_answers=[]} = data[0] || {};
const arr = [correct_answer, ...incorrect_answers]
```